# Print sheetnames on separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created some VBA code through which I create a list of all sheet names in my excel. Now I would like to print all the values in sheet "Blad2" in cell A1, A2, A3 etc...

Anybody some thoughts on how I can do this? Already got code below working but then its just overwriting the code in cell A2...

```
Sub namesSheet()

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Var = Sheets(i).Name
    Worksheets("Blad2").Range("A2") = Var
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set the counter for the cell too
    Sub namesSheet()

```
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Var = Sheets(i).Name
    Worksheets("Blad2").cells(i,1) = Var
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Worksheets("Blad2").Range("A1").Offset(RowOffset:=i) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub namesSheet()

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Var = Sheets(i).Name
    Worksheets("Blad2").Range("A" & i) = Var
Next i


End Sub
```